# Python: adding list to dictionary with padded zeros in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to import some lists to dictionary in python.

I wrote this code:

```
def merge_tuples(line_a, line_b, line_c):
    id_dict = dict()

    for line in line_a:
        if line[0] in id_dict:
            id_dict[line[0]].append(line[1])
        else:
            id_dict[line[0]] = [line[1]]

    for line in line_b:
        if line[0] in id_dict:
            id_dict[line[0]].append(line[1])
        else:
            id_dict[line[0]] = [line[1]]

    for line in line_c:
        if line[0] in id_dict:
            id_dict[line[0]].append(line[1])
        else:
            id_dict[line[0]] = [line[1]]

    return id_dict

if __name__ == "__main__":
     line_a = ((1, 3), (3, 4), (10, 2))
     line_b = ((1, 2), (2, 4), (5, 2))
     line_c = ((1, 5), (3, 2), (7, 3))
     print(merge_tuples(line_a, line_b, line_c))
```

and I got this result: `{1: [3, 2, 5], 2: [4], 3: [4, 2], 5: [2], 7: [3], 10: [2]}` which is correct.

Now, my question is, what I need to change, or what are the steps to get the result to look like this: `{1: [3, 2, 5], 2: [0, 4, 0], 3: [4, 0, 2], 5: [0, 2, 0], 7: [0, 0, 3],10: [2, 0, 0]}`

The first element of the list is considered to be ID.
Zero means that this ID wasn't found in first list.

Comment: You're repeating a lot of code in those for loops. Consider breaking that into a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be that the first time a new id is inserted in the dictionary, a list with 3 elements is created (with two null values).
Then, when inserting into an existing id, the corresponding element is replaced in the existing 3-elements list.

```
def merge_tuples(line_a, line_b, line_c):
    id_dict = dict()

    for line in line_a:
        if line[0] in id_dict:
            id_dict[line[0]].append(line[1])
        else:
            id_dict[line[0]] = [line[1], 0, 0]

    for line in line_b:
        if line[0] in id_dict:
            id_dict[line[0]][1] = line[1]
        else:
            id_dict[line[0]] = [0, line[1], 0]

    for line in line_c:
        if line[0] in id_dict:
            id_dict[line[0]][2] = line[1]
        else:
            id_dict[line[0]] = [0, 0, line[1]]

    return id_dict
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and modify your function to use `*args` so that iterating through `args` with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), the numbers are inserted at the index of each argument:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_tuples(*args):
    id_dict = defaultdict(lambda: [0]*len(args))
    for i, lines in enumerate(args):
        for line in lines:
            id_dict[line[0]][i] = line[1]
    return id_dict

if __name__ == "__main__":
     line_a = ((1, 3), (3, 4), (10, 2))
     line_b = ((1, 2), (2, 4), (5, 2))
     line_c = ((1, 5), (3, 2), (7, 3))
     print(merge_tuples(line_a, line_b, line_c))
     # {1: [3, 2, 5], 2: [0, 4, 0], 3: [4, 0, 2], 5: [0, 2, 0], 7: [0, 0, 3], 10: [2, 0, 0]})
```

---

This would also allow your function to handle a variable number of arguments and still produce the *right* results e.g.:

```
print(merge_tuples(line_a, line_b))
# {1: [3, 2], 10: [2, 0], 3: [4, 0], 2: [0, 4], 5: [0, 2]})
```